# Small bedroom recessed lighting

Tags: recessed-lighting

My 10x10 bedroom has one funky light fixture in the center. Can I get away with replacing it with one recessed light?

Comment: if you have room then yes

Comment: Flush Mount Lighting is common now even with LEDs. Recessed can be done with less beamwidth, but less glare at a distance.

Comment: Are you sure the beamwidth of the can is going to give enough spread to light the room adequately?

Comment: Why not just replace the objectionable fixture with a new more attractive surface mounted one that uses the same box? There is a box there, right? I ask this because I have seen cases where a ceiling fixture was wired without a box. I think this usually occurs in inexpensive construction where there was originally no ceiling fixture (the code required wall switch controlled a receptacle), then later someone with no respect for the code adds a ceiling fixture without a box.

Answer (score -1):

I wonder if one is enough to light up the whole room with it being recessed and all. You might wanna consider doing more than one.

Comment: Thanks all. I used an LED flush mounted fixture which provided plenty of light (and looks good, too). Liked it so well I replaced another fixture in spare room.

Comment: Come on. Let's see a picture